# The circuit that gives the higher-voltage one of the two input signals to output

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator, amplitude

I need a circuit that behaves as the box with the question mark in the graph I drew. I tried to design a few circuits with op-amps but I couldn't get an output as I wanted.

[image: Signal Graph]

Comment: Hint: Google for "peak detector circuit" and look at the "images" tab. You'll see plenty of circuits for one signal. Now try to combine two of those so that you get what you want.

Comment: Try two diode positive peak detectors, “diode OR” with no diode offset and unity gain. Or Consider Comparator for determining which input is greater and Analog Mux

Comment: In the title you ask for high amplitude, but the diagram shows you want higher voltage.  You should fix one or the other.  Passing the signal with the higher amplitude, as I originally thought you wanted, would be more complicated and would require more parameters.

Answer (score 8):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvc9T0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Two half-wave precision rectifiers.*

- Both op-amps will adjust their outputs to drive the inverting input to the same voltage as the non-inverting input.
- The higher input voltage, V1 or V2, will drive R1.
- The lower input voltage, V1 or V2, will drive its output to the negative rail in an attempt to bring the output down. It will fail due to the reverse biased output diode. This may affect recovery time when it has the higher voltage input.

[image]

*Figure 2. Input waveforms on top, output on bottom. Note that the output is clipped at about 11 V due to the 12 V power rail.*

Thanks to Spehro Pefhany for pointing out the need for power rails on the simulator.

---

Edit:

I found that I have given an almost identical answer to [Passing greater of 2 voltages using 5V signal](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/218496/passing-greater-of-2-voltages-using-5v-signal/218530#218530) some time ago.

Comment: +1 Worked okay for me, see deleted post below. I used op-amps with power supply rails, lower frequency and higher R but maybe only the first thing is important (otherwise the op-amps might go to hundreds of V negative on the output and break down the diodes)

Comment: They did go a few kV negative. I couldn't smell the diodes burning. Thanks!